# Drawing lines using for loops in JavaScript with p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

hello I am trying to draw a set of horizontal lines using for loops however I am getting this result:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 1000);
}

let space = 30;

background("lightblue");

rect(270, 170, 260, 165);

line(30, 20, 85, 75);
line(250, 170, 510, 170);

for (let y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
  for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    //rect(x * space + 250, y * space + 170, 15, 15);
    line(x * space + 250, x * space + 170, y * space + 400, y * space + 170);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

if someone could please show me how to draw one line right after the other I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I've created a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for you. Please update the code so it includes a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you had swapped usages of x and y in the second and third arguments to the `line()` call inside your nested for loops. The arguments expected are `line(x1, y1, x2, y2)`.

What was:

```
line(x * space + 250, x * space + 170, y * space + 400, y * space + 170);
```

should have been (everything is the same except y and x are swapped):

```
line(x * space + 250, y * space + 170, x * space + 400, y * space + 170);
```

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 1000);
}

let space = 30;

function draw() {
  background("lightblue");

  rect(270, 170, 260, 165);

  line(30, 20, 85, 75);
  line(250, 170, 510, 170);

  for (let y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
      //rect(x * space + 250, y * space + 170, 15, 15);
      line(
        x * space + 250,
        y * space + 170, // used to be x * space + 170
        x * space + 400, // used to be y * space + 400
        y * space + 170
      );
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```